# Promoting complex GADTs

Tags: haskell, gadt, dependent-type, data-kinds

I've been toying around with `-XDataKinds` recently, and was wondering why `Foo` below won't be automatically promoted:

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    GADTs
  , DataKinds
  , KindSignatures #-}

import Data.HList

data Foo a where
  Foo :: Bar a =>
         a -> Foo a

data Baz where
  Baz :: (a ~ HList (l :: [Foo *])) =>
         a -> Baz
```

That is, `Baz` is a heterogenous list of `Foo a`'s, where `a` is constrained by `Bar`.

Is there a way to manually create a promoted version of this data type? How would I go about doing so? Can kinds be *declared*? Could I make a dummy Haskell98 version of `Foo`, and separate it into a module or something? Ideally I'd like to keep the constraint context, but I don't think there's a `Constraint` sort. Any ideas would be very helpful!

Comment: I'm wondering if I could just (somehow) declare a kind, then make `Foo` the only inhabitant of it.

Comment: With some small changes I got [this](https://gist.github.com/ec1ab70974c4d6d7f6b9) to work.  Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?  I can't explain why it works, but it does compile.

Comment: Ahh, you're very correct, this is exactly what I needed. The kind signature wasn't necessary!

Comment: I also had to change it to `'[]` instead, but again I don't know enough about `DataKinds` to tell you why this version works in particular.

Comment: `Foo` is unpromotable, since GADTs in general are unpromotable (in this specific case, it is because of the constraint). If you try `:kind! 'Foo` in ghci, you will see this. `Foo` refers to the type constructor `Foo`, not the data constructor, when used in `Baz`. Although `Baz` is a very boring type because `HList ('[Foo b])` is essentially just `Foo b`, and `b` is existentially quantified so `Baz` is equivalent to `data Baz = forall a . Bar a => Baz a`. I don't know if this is what you want, but somehow I doubt it.

Comment: @user2407038 You're right, I didn't realize `'[Foo b]` was a singleton. Crud. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @AthanClark If you need a heterogeneous list of types each of which satisfies some constraint, just have an `HList` and a class which recurses through the list and does whatever to each element.

Comment: @user2407038 Something that worked for me, actually was to put a kind signature on `l`, like in my question, but make it higher kinded, then supply a parameter `b` and bind it to `FooLike a`. Phew!

@bheklilr Would you like to issue the answer?